# Make LSTM learn from the correlation of 3 variables

Tags: tensorflow, machine-learning, keras, deep-learning, lstm

I have a dataset of 3 variables x,y,z. and they are the readings of 3 different sensors. These will be the inputs.

When these sensors find a specific object, the corresponding output of their readings should 1. Otherwise the corresponding output of there readings should be 0.

This is example when they find the object
 [image: This is example when they find the object]

and this is example when they don't find the object
[image]

What I want to do is to make a Neural Network (probably an LSTM) or any other method that receives the sensors readings and tell if they are finding the object or not.
Note that the values of the sensor outputs are not usually the same as in the figures, but what I noticed is the correlation between the readings and distance between them.

What is the best way to implement that?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The "best" model is "art". You have to test and test until you have one that suits your data well.

But basically, you will have inputs with shape `(examples, time_steps, features)`, where:

- `examples` = any value, the more the better
- `time_steps` = the length (number of readings) for each example
- `features = 3`.

You will then create a model that starts with:

```
inputs = Input((None, 3)) #variable time_steps, 3 features
```

You're probably going to benefit from using a normalization of these values, probably with a Batch normalization layer:

```
outputs = BatchNormalization()(inputs)
outputs = Activation('tanh')(outputs)
```

Then you start the LSTM part of the model (the number of layers depends on your tests)

```
#any number of layers similar to this (this can also be 0)
outputs = LSTM(units, return_sequences=True, activation='tanh')(outputs)

#the last LSTM layer
outputs = LSTM(units, return_sequences=False, activation='tanh')(outputs)
```

You may or may not add extra classification layers, such as:

```
#any number of classification layers, including 0
outputs = Dense(units)(outputs)
outputs = BatchNormalization()(outputs)
outputs = Activation('relu')(outputs)

#last classification:
outputs = Dense(1)(outputs)
outputs = BatchNormalization()(outputs)
outputs = Activatoin('sigmoid')(outputs)
```

Finally, join everything:

```
model = Model(intpus, outputs)
```

Please notice that this is just an example of model. This can vary A LOT (including branches, poolings, attention mechanisms, etc..., but your problem seems simple enough).

The important parts here are:

- Understanding the input shape
- Understanding that in the last LSTM you're discarding the "time_steps" dimension.

  - Now your problem is 2D - `(examples, units_or_features)`
- Understanding that your last layer must have one unit only. (So it can return a single result per example)

  - Your output data must also match this shape: `(examples, 1)`
- Understanding that the last activation should be 'sigmoid', so the result is between 0 and 1.

Comment: This was quick and detailed answer. Thank you.

Comment: Just one more detail, how should I organize the inputs? If I have a file with 3 columns having the readings values, how to specify corresponding output value for a set of values? Should it be ones or zeros besides all the rows?

Comment: What do you want to achieve? Classification per step or single classification per sequence?

Comment: I want to classify Per sequence

Comment: Then the answer contains that info: `Your output data must match this shape: (examples, 1)`. One class per sequence.

Comment: While the input data (`x_train`) is `(samples, length, 3)`, the output/target/ground_truth (`y_train`) is `(samples, 1)`.